# (MagicalRecord) NSDate in relatedByAttribute

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, magicalrecord

I have an object I'm importing using **MagicalRecord** with the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "receipts": [
        {
             "date": "2014/03/05",
             "amount": "199.00"
        },
        {
             "date": "2014/03/04",
             "amount": "9.00"
        },
        {
             "date": "2014/03/01",
             "amount": "9.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

In CoreData I've created a **Receipt** object with two values, date and amount. The business requirements state that the date will always be unique. As such, I'd like to use it for 'relatedByAttribute' for that NSManagedObject. However, MagicalRecord throughs this error when I do:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178034500'
```

In CoreData on the **Reciept** object, I have the date attribute set as "relatedByAttribute". On the date attribute itself I set "dateFormat: yyyy/MM/dd" in the User Info as well. I also have a **Commission** object with a relationship to this **Receipt** with the relationship setup as "relatedByAttribute : date".

In Sum:
Is there a way to set an NSDate as the primary key using "relatedByAttribute"?

For all those interested, further details of this issue are being discussed through MagicalRecord's issue tracker [here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/740#issuecomment-41047513).

Comment: Would you mind filing this as an issue on the MagicalRecord issue tracker, along with the version of MR you're using and the full backtrace of that exception? I'll take a look into it.

Comment: I just posted the issue (NSDate in "relatedByAttribute" #740) here (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/740)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve the issue I added an *identifier* property on my *Reciept* object. I made it a string and set *mappedKeyName* to *date*. I then kept my existing *date* property as is (i.e. *dateFormat* to *yyyy/MM/dd*). I then changed my relatedByAttribute to *identifier*. It works like a charm!

The big "AHA!" for me was when I realized that MagicalRecord lets you map multiple properties to the same JSON attribute. Now my *date* property is an NSDate just like a want and I also have a unique string *identifier*.

Comment: you save me in 2015 mate i was also facing the same issue , solved now